# Production count grouped for every 10 seconds

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I want to show the production count for last one hour grouped for every 10 seconds.
So far I have done this

```
SELECT 

COUNT(*) AS [PRODUCTION],
(DATEPART(HOUR, DATEADD(SECOND, -(DATEPART(SECOND, TL_Timestamp)) % 10, TL_Timestamp))) AS [HOUR],
(DATEPART(MINUTE, DATEADD(SECOND, -(DATEPART(SECOND, TL_Timestamp)) % 10, TL_Timestamp))) AS [MIN],
(DATEPART(SECOND, DATEADD(SECOND, -(DATEPART(SECOND, TL_Timestamp)) % 10, TL_Timestamp))) AS [FROMSECOND]

FROM tblTransaction
WHERE TL_Timestamp BETWEEN  DATEADD(HOUR,-1, GETDATE())  AND GETDATE()
AND TL_IsAccepted = 1
GROUP BY 
(DATEPART(HOUR, DATEADD(SECOND, -(DATEPART(SECOND, TL_Timestamp)) % 10, TL_Timestamp))),
(DATEPART(MINUTE, DATEADD(SECOND, -(DATEPART(SECOND, TL_Timestamp)) % 10, TL_Timestamp))),
(DATEPART(SECOND, DATEADD(SECOND, -(DATEPART(SECOND, TL_Timestamp)) % 10, TL_Timestamp)))
ORDER BY 
(DATEPART(HOUR, DATEADD(SECOND, -(DATEPART(SECOND, TL_Timestamp)) % 10, TL_Timestamp))) DESC,
(DATEPART(MINUTE, DATEADD(SECOND, -(DATEPART(SECOND, TL_Timestamp)) % 10, TL_Timestamp))) DESC,
(DATEPART(SECOND, DATEADD(SECOND, -(DATEPART(SECOND, TL_Timestamp)) % 10, TL_Timestamp))) DESC
```

This is working fine but its not taking into account if the production has not happened for whole 10 seconds. I want it to be zero.
Any ideas?

Comment: see the link referenced to know on  how to ask a perfect question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a table with all the timestamp groups (prepopulated and fixed), and put it as the first table in the join (the other in left join to it).

Eg. (they should be 360 records in your case, ie for a single hour, or 8640 for a whole day )

```
ID   MIN SEC  
1    00 10  
2    00 20  
3    00 30
```

...
If you call it `TL_TIME_DIVISION`

```
SELECT TL_TIME_DIVISION.HOUR, TL_TIME_DIVISION.MIN, TL_TIME_DIVISION.SEC, COALESCE (PRODUCTION,0)  AS PRODUCTION
FROM TL_TIME_DIVISION   
LEFT JOIN **your query** ON **use Hour, min e sec**
```